# Versions of Daniel not Mentioning Darius in the Sixth or Ninth Chapter

Tags: textual-criticism, daniel, historical-criticism, dating

There are three *main* versions of the *[Book of Daniel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Daniel)* : [Masoretic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masoretic_Text), [Old Greek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Septuagint), and [Theodotion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theodotion). However, they all read [Darius](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darius_II) (but allude to [Cyrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrus_the_Great)) in both their [sixth](http://www.greekdoc.com/bible/polyglot/daniel06.html) and [ninth](http://www.greekdoc.com/bible/polyglot/daniel09.html) chapters.

Are there any alternate versions or textual variations, lacking this particular name in *at least one* of these two chapters (except perhaps in the final verse of chapter six, where its presence or absence is irrelevant to my research) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such versions would be mentioned in the [BHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblia_Hebraica_Stuttgartensia). The BHS has no notes to his name in 6:2 and 9:1, so it's safe to assume that such versions do not exist (from [my comment](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/41715/versions-of-daniel-not-mentioning-darius-in-the-sixth-or-ninth-chapter?noredirect=1#comment83236_41715)).

You can find [a copy of the BHS on archive.org](https://archive.org/details/BibliaHebraicaStuttgartensiaBHS5th/page/n1427). Here is [the page](https://archive.org/details/BibliaHebraicaStuttgartensiaBHS5th/page/n1427) with the beginning of Daniel 6:

> [image]

The note to Darius in 6:1 tells you that in the Old Greek his name is Artaxerxes. To his name in 6:2 there is no note.

Here are the first lines of chapter 9 (from [this page](https://archive.org/details/BibliaHebraicaStuttgartensiaBHS5th/page/n1433)):

> [image]

As you can see, there is no note.

Comment: Thank you for the relevant and meaningful contribution. To the random reader : The MT verse numbering differs from the KJV, in that 5:31 becomes 6:1, and 6:1 becomes 6:2.